# Best way to estimate OpenGL frames per second on iOS is *not* Apple's Instruments?

Tags: performance, opengl-es, instruments

We have an App based on Apple's [GLCameraRipple](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/#samplecode/GLCameraRipple/Introduction/Intro.html) example which does realtime image processing on video from the iOS device's camera.

Apple's Instruments reports that OpenGL is running at ~30-40fps (which is one frame every 25-30 ms.)  This makes sense assuming the video is being captured and processed at ~30fps.

However, if we measure the time between calls to glkView:drawInRect using mach_absolute_time the loop time is 50 ms (which is ~20 fps.)  That rate is almost half as slow as reported by Instruments.

So is Apple's Instruments wrong (by almost 100%(!)) - or is timing calls to glkView:drawInRect wrong?

It would seem that Apple's Instruments is inaccurate as isn't glkView:drawInRect called on every draw cycle?

We found [others](http://www.iphonedevsdk.com/forum/iphone-sdk-tools-utilities/14874-recorded-milliseconds-fps-vs-instruments-fps.html) have noted the same discrepancy but have no clear answer as to which is actually correct.

Why the discrepancy? If Apple's instruments is wrong - is measuring round-trip time to glkView:drawInRect the right approach to determine FPS?

Comment: I don't know the answer, but you could always measure it yourself. Increment a `long` variable every frame, run for 5 minutes, divide and find the average frame time.

Comment: I believe that is exactly what we did.  If the correct method to measure for the timestamp between each frame is glkView:drawInRect, then the timing you recommend is essentially exactly what we did.  The result was 50ms - which suggests Apple's Instruments is inaccurate (and off by almost 100%).  The core question is whether glkView:drawInRect is the correct place to timestamp between frames - or is there another method that is better representative of frame rate?